# IE11 and Edge slow linkProgram

Tags: internet-explorer, glsl, webgl, microsoft-edge

I've started running into strange performance problems under IE11 and Edge in relation to `WebGLRenderingContext.linkProgram`. Whereas every other platform that I target (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Chrome Android, Firefox Android and iOS Safari) successfully link all my shaders in a few milliseconds, IE11 and Edge hang the main thread for up to 4 seconds! This happens *both* on a nVidia GTX laptop and an i7 only laptop.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to what could be causing this- the shaders are all large, (including a large common library at the top of each fragment shader), yet only one of them really chokes hard.

UPDATE:

It seems that using the following function is causing the grief:

```c
float getShadowCoefficient() {
    if(shadowType == SHADOW_SINGLE)
        return shadowDepthSingle();
    if(shadowType == SHADOW_LERP4)
        return shadowDepthLerp4();
    if(shadowType == SHADOW_PCF)
        return shadowDepthPCF();
    if(shadowType == SHADOW_PCF_LERP)
        return shadowDepthPCFLerp();
    if(shadowType == SHADOW_VSM)
        return shadowDepthVSM();
    return 1.0;
}
```

Yes. It's an ubershader driven by uniforms rather than `#ifdef`. Precisely to avoid this kind of slow startup.

The only plausible explanation for this incredibly slow compile I can come up with currently is somehow IE and Edge are expanding these calls into all the shader combinations. Does this seem likely?

Comment: Yes it's possible sadly. DirectX can take minutes to compile a complex shader with full optimization on. You should consider [filing a bug with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE)

(Note: I'm assuming Edge uses DirectX for WebGL behind the scenes the same way Chrome and Firefox do on Windows)

Comment: Thanks for that, I suspected as much.  I have filed a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/2451805/uniform-based-ubershader-program-linking-unbearably-slow-under-webgl-in-ie-and-edge-compared-to-other-browsers-including-mobile-browsers).  And yes- IE and Edge use DirectX behind the scenes.  Strangely so do chrome and firefox, where this issue is not noticable, but they both rely on the same [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software)) implementation.

Comment: IIRC they turned off optimization in DirectX on ANGLE precisely because of this issue.